# RESTapi login issue

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5

I have the following login API.

```
public function login() {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            $agency = new AgencyResource(Agency::find($user->agency_id));
            $success['agency'] = $agency;
            return response()->json(['responseCode' => '101', 'responseMessage' => 'Login successful', 'data' => $success], $this->successStatus);

        } else {
            return response()->json(['responseCode' => '102', 'responseMessage' => 'Invalid username or password', 'data' => null], 401);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I check in the postman with wrong credentials I get the following response.

```
{
    "responseCode": "102",
    "responseMessage": "Invalid username or password",
    "data": null
}
```

Which is correct. But the same api gives the following response on Android Device not in json format.

```
   Result in Failure:
[Failure: Exception : HTTP Exception 401 Unauthorized]
```

**Question:** I need to have response as what is given by postman. Please help

I use laravel 5.5

Comment: These are the same responses? The second one only contains the response headers?!

Comment: I don't get the problem actually, the response in Android seems ok isnt it ?? You have your status code 401 aswell as the rest of the content in Body... :/

Comment: Oh, do you mean its not parsed the same way? I guess you have to manually retrieve the info you want from the Android Device response

Comment: sorry. please check my updated question.

Comment: Have you looked if the exception object has a body/message? This field should contain the wanted json object!?

Comment: @FMK, how to add this exception to the response? I am still learning laravel

Comment: The exception in you android code should contain the necessary data! Your backend is returning all necessary data!

Comment: So in the backend I do not need to add anything right?